# How to disable the title in select2

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

I've a select2 dropdown which looks like this :

```
    $(function () {
  $("#itemSelect").select2().on("select2:select", function (e) {
   $("#itemSelect").val(-1).trigger("change");
        var id = e.params.data.title;
        var url = siteRoot + "/site/item?itemID=" + id ;
        $("#Container").load(url);
    });
});
```

It gets it's values from my Model in html:

```
<select class="js-data-example-ajax" aria-expanded="true" style="width: 100%; display: none;" id="itemSelect">
<option disabled selected value="-1"> Search by item </option>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <option text="@item.Id" title="@item.Id">
        item.Name
    </option>
}
```

Everything works fine, EXCEPT when I choose an item and it's loaded, I can hover over the dropdown and it shows me the ID from the item. I don't want to show the ID!

[image]

In the picture you see the dropdown and the item number which appears when I hover over "Ice Tea"

I know it's because select2 gets the id by `var id = e.params.data.title;`, but how can I change this? 
It's not working with  `var id = e.params.data.id;`

I tried to use tooltip, but I'm new to this.

```
//$("#select2-itemSelect-container").tooltip({
//    title: "Search item",

//    placement: "auto"
//});
```

I just want to get rid of the ID in the dropdown while hover over. 
Every help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think I understand where the ID is being displayed and in what manner.  Could you please post an example or screenshot of the issue.  It sounds like you have another script that is showing the ID...

Comment: I have posted an answer, but I am not overly confident in it being correct.  It might also help to post a jsfiddle if no one else can figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

I might be a bit late, but non of this solutions worked for me since I was dynamically adding select2 fields to UI.

This code did the trick for me:

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').hover(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('title');
});
```

If you are also dynamically adding select2 fields don't forget always to execute this code before above one:

```
$('.select2-selection__rendered').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

This code will first remove `on hover` listener on all select2 fields.

Comment: Or simply do it for whole document and all `.select2-selection__rendered` elements that may appear anytime with `$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select2-selection__rendered', function () { $(this).removeAttr('title');  });`

Comment: @JánJanočko Works fine with you code also.

Answer (score 7):

The problem can be reproduced in **Select2 v4** by placing the mouse over the select box (in single selection mode) or over the selected tags (in multiple selection mode):

[image]
[image]

The plugin attaches a `title` attribute to these elements by default, and there is no configuration option available to disable this behaviour.

I had ended up writing a small extension for the `Select2` plugin.
I've added a new option, `selectionTitleAttribute`, which must be set to false to remove the `title` attribute.

Add the following code right after the plugin's `js` file:

```
;(function($) {

  // Extend defaults
  //
  var Defaults = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/defaults');

  $.extend(Defaults.defaults, {
    selectionTitleAttribute: true
  });

  // SingleSelection
  //
  var SingleSelection = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/selection/single');

  var _updateSingleSelection = SingleSelection.prototype.update;

  SingleSelection.prototype.update = function(data) {

    // invoke parent method
    _updateSingleSelection.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

    var selectionTitleAttribute = this.options.get('selectionTitleAttribute');

    if (selectionTitleAttribute === false) {
      var $rendered = this.$selection.find('.select2-selection__rendered');
      $rendered.removeAttr('title');
    }

  };


  // MultipleSelection
  //
  var MultipleSelection = $.fn.select2.amd.require('select2/selection/multiple');

  var _updateMultipleSelection = MultipleSelection.prototype.update;

  MultipleSelection.prototype.update = function(data) {

    // invoke parent method
    _updateMultipleSelection.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

    var selectionTitleAttribute = this.options.get('selectionTitleAttribute');

    if (selectionTitleAttribute === false) {
      var $rendered = this.$selection.find('.select2-selection__rendered');
      $rendered.find('.select2-selection__choice').removeAttr('title');
      this.$selection.find('.select2-selection__choice__remove').removeAttr('title');
    }

  };

})(window.jQuery);
```

#### Usage

Initialize the select2 plugin with the `selectionTitleAttribute` option set to `false`:

```
$("select").select2({
  // other options 
  selectionTitleAttribute: false
});
```

#### Demo

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr8bqnpn/

Comment: Can you possibly submit this as a PR for Select2? Looks like there is a help-wanted https://github.com/select2/select2/pull/3988

Comment: Please submit this to the git.

Comment: I added "this.$selection.find('.select2-selection__choice__remove').removeAttr('title');" In the multipleSelection part, to remove the "Remove" title on the button.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You can use events to remove title tag.

For example, this code works with select2 v4.0:

```
$('select').on('change', function (evt) {
    $('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/by8k1dv9/

Answer (score 2):

After initializing select2, use below line of code to remove title attribute from select2 options from code. remove ` sign then put in your script file

```
   $("ul.select2-selection__rendered").hover(function(){
      $(this).find('li').removeAttr('title');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

hey everyone if you have this problem this simple trick

```
<script>

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select2-selection__rendered',  function () {


    $(this).removeAttr("title");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the tooltip for the created select2.

```
$(function () {
    $("#itemSelect").select2().on("select2:select", function (e) {
        $("#itemSelect").val(-1).trigger("change");
        var id = e.params.data.title;
        var url = siteRoot + "/site/item?itemID=" + id ;
        $("#Container").load(url);
    }).tooltip('disable');
});
```

Comment: Could you please provide a JSFiddle with the issue?  I feel like I am overlooking something since I cannot replicate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuntely I didn't have any luck with the above solutions, possibly because this project uses bootstrap and Select2 was utilising bootstrap tooltips, which look different and fade in.

In this case, upon mouseover, Select2 would actually remove the `title` attribute, replacing it with `aria-describedby` which contained an id of a newly-created toolip element. On mouseleave, `aria-describedby` was removed and the `title` attribute restored again.

So trying to remove the `title` attribute didn't work, as it had already been removed, and then it was restored again on mouseleave. So this did the trick for me:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.select2-selection__rendered', function () {
  var tooltipId = $(this).attr("aria-describedby"); // contains the id of the tooltip
  $("#" + tooltipId).hide(); // hide the tooltip before it fades in
  $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); // stop it showing another tooltip
});
```

The above code doesn't prevent Select2 from attempting to show a tooltip the *first* time the mouse hovers over it, but `.hide()` successfully prevents it being shown before it starts to fade in. After that, unbinding the hover stops Select2 from trying to show any more of them.

Answer (score 0):

I trying use this, and it's works :

```
        $(document).on('mouseenter', '.select2-selection__rendered', function () {
            $('.select2-selection__rendered').removeAttr('title');
        });
```