# Remove title from select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using [select2](https://select2.org). I need to remove `title` of selected values. My code is like below.

```
<li class="select2-selection__choice" title="C Volunteer" data-select2-id="select2-data-16-lf0b"></li>
```

Source code is like below.

[image]

Output is like below.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500508/how-to-disable-the-title-in-select2/46327202#46327202

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable the title in select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500508/how-to-disable-the-title-in-select2)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal solution for your use case:

```
$("#select2-data-16-lf0b").removeAttr("title")
```

Comment: Thanks @josefdzbeta. Could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2

Answer (score 1):

You can select the elements by their class and remove its attribute this way.

```
$('.select2-selection__choice').removeAttr('title')
```

hope have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution to select the selected options. This will work at any action either its selection or unselection.

```
$("yourselector").on("select2:select select2:unselect", function (e) {
    $(this).removeAttr("title");       
});
```

This may help you

Comment: Thanks @Saeed Ahmed. Could you please help me in this post ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71043039/tooltip-is-not-closing-with-select2